# Can we have protocol with implementation?

Tags: objective-c, protocols

I want to set a singletonProtocol. Classes that implement that protocol will support +(id) singleton

Obviously I will implement that singleton method. It's a waste to re implement the same thing again and again.

I can use inheritance, I already knows how to do it, but a class can only have one parent and using inheritance sounds like an overkill. Basically I will just store the singletons in an NSMutableDictionary whose key is the NSStringFromClass of the respective class. I wonder why no one else do that. It's the same technique I used for [In Objective-c how can we have a variable whose scope is the whole class (but doesn't include subclasses)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13738109/in-objective-c-how-can-we-have-a-variable-whose-scope-is-the-whole-class-but-do)

```
#import "BGSuperSingleton.h"

static NSMutableDictionary * allTheSingletons;
@implementation BGSuperSingleton

+(id) singleton1
{
    NSString* className = NSStringFromClass([self class]);

    id result = allTheSingletons[className];

    if (result==nil)
    {
        result = [[[self class] alloc]init];
        allTheSingletons[className]=result;
    }
    return result;
}

@end
```

I can use category. However, category works for virtually any classes. I can limit that all my singletons belong to SuperSingleton class but that would defeat the purpose

I can use protocol. Now that's awesome. However, protocol does not have implementation. Protocol only declares method a class can do.

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, what should I do?

You should reconsider your design. It sounds like you want to adopt this protocol in a number of different classes so that you can have a shared instance of each of those classes. Do those objects really *need* to be singletons? There's a difference between a shared object and a class that *must not* be instantiated more than once.

Consider creating a class that acts as a factory for all the other classes. That class can maintain the dictionary of shared objects, and you can simply make a point of always using the factory to instantiate the other classes. Indeed, you can write the other classes such that instantiating them directly throws an exception or something.

Comment: That would be another approach. A class with effectively tons of singletons.